# It turned out not the case vs it turned out not to be the case

Tags: idioms, syntax

"It turned out not the case" or "it turned out not to be the case" - which is more correct?

Comment: "It turned out to not be the case"/"It turned out to be not the case"/"It turned out not to be the case" - all are correct. Among them "It turned out not to be the case" is more common. But the best way of saying this is - "It didn't turn out to be the case."

Comment: The first version *("It turned out not the case")* is ***not*** really valid English, since strictly speaking the word ***be*** should be there. And since *[not] being the case* is relatively formal phrasing, it's a very unlikely reduction that would normally be corrected by any alert copy-editor. Variants based on ***didn't** turn out* are also relatively unlikely for much the same reason (such use of auxiliary ***do*** is somewhat informal, so it doesn't fit so naturally with *being the case*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Are my alternatives natural from the point of view of a native speaker?

Comment: @Man_From_India: To my ear, the only really credible variant is OP's (and your) last suggestion: *"It turned out **not to be** the case"*. It's the best of a bad bunch (because ***to turn out*** is slightly informal, whereas ***to be the case*** is slightly formal) but it's probably the best you can do if you're determined to use both those two elements in the same sentence. Depending on the exact context it might be better to start from scratch and go for something straightforward such as ***...which didn't happen***.

Comment: @Man_From_India: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I suspect your "formal knowledge" of English (in terms of "grammatical rules") is actually quite extensive by comparison to your "informal knowledge" (of the forms native speakers tend to favour). Perhaps because (sometimes quite rightly, imho) you're wary of accepting "Indian English" as a valid standard. So just to clarify my earlier comments in the context of your previous ones, rest assured that all three of your alternatives are perfectly "valid". It's just that they're all to some extent "awkward" or "non-favoured".

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are absolutely right. I have been grown up listening to Indian English. But again sometimes they are not standard, believe me in some places you would find completely wrong sentences being on display. Anyways, as a person with English as a second language, I will always need a helping hand from native speakers in terms of what is natural to their ears. Of course they will vary depending on the people from various corners. Now coming back to this topic, after I have suggested those sentences I have checked corpus, and they seem to reflect exactly what you pointed out. :)

Comment: @Man_From_India: oic. So you have an *extra* problem because some of the "non-standard" usages you encounter are actually perfectly acceptable to people who (from their perspective) are fluent in English ("standard" IE tends to use present continuous where other Anglophones use simple present, for example). But other usages are simply out-and-out errors, and it's probably hard for you to tell which is which. You have my utmost sympathy! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers :) I don't know what people who view those non-standard uses think, but they people who wrote them are not at all well-versed with English :) I only wish that other people who view those wrong uses don't get an impression that those usages are standard IE :) that's all :)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out not the case vs it turned out not to be the case.

The verbal phrase "turn out" is used in different senses. When it means "to be found or discovered", we usually use  + to be/that after it.  Please see the following examples.

Adam turned out not to be suitable person for the post.

He turned out not  to be a friend of my brother.

So it sounds natural to say that "it turned out not to be the case".

Comment: I think it's also correct to say "it turned out to be not the case".

Comment: I'm not a grammar expert, but "it turned out to be not the case" sounds wrong to me. Or perhaps it just sounds unnatural and awkward. I would not recommend using that phrase.

Comment: http://www.delcotimes.com/opinion/20140523/the-herons-nest-when-allegations-turn-out-to-be-not-the-case